# Difference between MOSS 2007 and WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint-2007

hello i have developed a sharepoint 2007 site using  MOSS 2007  and wss 3.0. i want to know difference between both. if i deploy this site to another serserver with moss 2007 installed but no wss 3.0, will that site work fine??

thnks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOSS 2007 is a product built on top of WSS 3.0.

WSS 3.0 is a set of services provided by Microsoft for free which provides basic capabilities for Document Management.

When you install MOSS 2007 on a server, WSS 3.0 is automatically installed with it.

Check out this link:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4